# What is involved in changing the admin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, admin

One of the security measures for Wordpress is to get rid of the admin. I've tried this before by creating another user and giving them admin rights. Then I changed the 'author' of the posts that I have on the website to the new user and I removed the admin user.

Wrong move. I lost all the pages now. I had to make sure that I changed the author of the pages to the new user as well.
At least.. that's my guess.

Is there anything else that I need to do before trying again?
(I can change the author of the media.. but that's a pain to do, since you cannot do this in bulk, afaik)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess no one knows (or cares to share). I decided not to get rid of the admin, but simply give the admin a different function (not admin anymore)... and everything seems to work...